# Deal with rows and colums (months) in sqlachemy + python

Tags: python, matrix, sqlalchemy, row

I've to create a database model (sqlalchemy) for a table with rows (fields) and a month for a row :

```
-field one (firstname):   J | F | M | A | M | J | J ...
-field two (lastname):    J | F | M | A | M | J | J ...
-field three (age) :      J | F | M | A | M | J | J ...
-field four ... :         J | F | M | A | M | J | J ...
```

Almost a matrix...

I want to create a record per month with a key/enum for a "month's name".

So, 12 records per one month, and so on.
It's the best approach ?

Thanks
F.